# Prometheus with Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, prometheus

I have the following *Dockerfile*:

```
FROM prom/prometheus
ADD prometheus.yml /etc/prometheus/
```

with *prometheus.yml*:

```
global:
scrape_interval: 15s

external_labels:
  monitor: 'codelab-monitor'

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    metrics_path: /metrics
    scrape_interval: 15s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9090']

  - job_name: 'auth-service'
    scrape_interval: 15s
    metrics_path: /actuator/prometheus
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:8080']
```

And run it with the following command:

```
docker build -t prometheus .
docker run -d -p 9090:9090 --rm prometheus
```

> prometheus has status **up**
>
> auth-service has status **down** (*Get "http://localhost:8080/actuator/prometheus": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused*)

How can I solve problem with **auth-service**, because from local machine I can get metrics from this address *http://localhost:8080/actuator/prometheus*:

```
v.balun@macbook-vbalun Trainter-Prometheus % curl -X GET 
http://localhost:8080/actuator/prometheus
# HELP jvm_memory_committed_bytes The amount of memory in bytes that is committed for the 
Java virtual machine to use
# TYPE jvm_memory_committed_bytes gauge
jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="heap",id="G1 Survivor Space",} 4194304.0
jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="heap",id="G1 Old Gen",} 3.145728E7
jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="nonheap",id="Metaspace",} 3.0982144E7
jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="nonheap",id="CodeHeap 'non-nmethods'",} 2555904.0
jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="heap",id="G1 Eden Space",} 2.7262976E7
jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="nonheap",id="Compressed Class Space",} 4325376.0
jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="nonheap",id="CodeHeap 'non-profiled nmethods'",} 6291456.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having seems not related to prometheus, it seems it is at the docker network level.

Inside your `prometheus` container you are saying this:

```
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:8080']
```

But remember that `localhost` is NOT now your physical host (*As when you ran it locally outside Docker*), it's now inside the container, and inside the same container most likely you don't have your service running...

With the information provided I suggest you the following:

1. Try first instead `localhost` use your real IP, depending on the network configuration you are using for your container, it will be enough...
2. You can use instead `localhost` the ip address of your `auth-service`, this is the one given by docker, you can run a `docker inspect...` to get it.
3. If #1 and #2 didn't work and if `auth-service` is running in another container inside the same physical host, then you could use a bridge network to make the communication between the containers possible, more details here: https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/
    Once both containers are running in the same network you can use the container name to reference it instead `localhost`, something like:

```
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['auth-service:8080']
```